# Reachability block application

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, connection-string, reachability

in my app in the appDelegate .m i have insert the reachability code like apple say:

```
-(BOOL)checkInternet
{
Reachability *r = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"google.com"];
NetworkStatus internetStatus = [r currentReachabilityStatus];
BOOL internet;
if ((internetStatus != ReachableViaWiFi) && (internetStatus != ReachableViaWWAN)) {
    internet = NO;
} else {
    internet = YES;
}
return internet;
}
```

and in my viewcontroller.m in the method - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {

```
gotInternet = [self checkInternet];
if ( gotInternet == 0)
{
//No connection
} else {
//Connection ok
}
```

but when there are problems on the network 3g my application after about 20 seconds it crashes because of too much latency. How do I implement the control connection asynchronously, never to take the watchdog?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at `NSOperation` and the [concurrency programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091).